# How to optimize memory allocations inside a C++11 function returning a vector without breaking client code

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, vector

I have a C++11 function that returns a vector:

```
std::vector<int> foo(int i) {
  std::vector<int> ret;
  ret.push_back(20 + i);
  return ret;
}
```

This function is already published and used in multiple locations in client code. For some use cases, foo is used at very high frequency and for these use cases the cost of vector allocations is prohibitive. I can't break the client code for the other use cases.

The objective is to modify foo to enable re-use of already allocated vectors when available. This must be done in a way that does not break existing client.

The first thing I could think of was:

**Option 1:** having two different `foo` functions:

```
void foo(int i, std::vector<int> &ret) {
  ret.clear();
  ret.push_back(20 + i);
}
std::vector<int> foo(int i) {
  std::vector<int> ret;
  foo(i, ret);
  return ret;
}
```

This works as expected but the drawback is that there are now two functions instead of just one. I was wondering if there would be a good way to achieve the same result but without adding a new function.

I could think of (somewhat bad) ways to get the expected optimization without adding a new function:

**Option 2:** using a static thread_local temporary

```
std::vector<int> &&foo(int i) {
  static thread_local std::vector<int> ret;
  ret.clear();
  ret.push_back(20 + i);
  return std::move(ret);
}
```

This meets the requirements but the usage is surprising as the user has to write `foo(i).swap(vector)` to get the benefit of the optimization. Also, the static variable does add some measurable overhead.

**Option 3:** using an rvalue reference parameter with default value

```
std::vector<int> foo(int i, std::vector<int> &&ret = std::vector<int>()) {
  ret.clear();
  ret.push_back(20 + i);
  return std::move(ret);
}
```

**Edit:** the return value in this case can be (and probably should be) `std::vector<int>` instead of `std::vector<int> &&`. If `foo`was returning `std::vector<int> &&`, the outcome of `vector = foo(i, std::move(vector))` could be surprising (with gcc, that would be an empty vector).

Faster than **option 2** above but the usage is atrocious. It now requires the user to write `foo(i, std::move(vector))` to get the benefit of the optimization.

The specific questions would be:

- What are the good alternatives that I missed?
- Is there a way to achieve the same result as option 2 but without the overhead of the static local variable?
- Is there a way to achieve the same result as option 3 but that ensures that the user can't write `vector = foo(i, std::move(vector))`?

Comment: What's exactly wrong with `vector = foo(i, std::move(vector))`?

Comment: @Fureeish Very good question. I guess that the reason I am getting into trouble is because the return type of the function is `std::vector<int> &&` which seemed to be consistent with the `return std::move(ret)`. But thinking about it, I guess that if the return type was just `std::vector<int>` everything would work fine. Thanks.

Comment: I have a tough time conceiving of a situation/compiler in which any of these alternatives would be faster than your initial base case.  Are you sure you're not doing something silly like benchmarking without enabling optimization?

Comment: @ChrisDodd never sure that I am not doing something silly. I tried on an ubuntu VirtualBox, with gcc (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0 using `g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -O3 `. Over 10 million iterations, the initial base case is approx 2 seconds. Option 1 and option 3 are approx 30 milliseconds. On a better server running CentOs 7 with gcc 4.8.5 (still using `-std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -O3`) I get respectively 850ms and 30 ms.

Comment: What are your constraints exactly? You talk about "not breaking client code" and "this function is already published", but then every single one of your proposed solutions changes `foo` (except Option 1, which doesn't appear to achieve anything?)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit by "not breaking client code" I mean that after the change, all existing (and reasonable) client code still compile and still produce the expected result. Option 1 achieves this by adding a new function and not making any change to the declaration of the original function. Option 2 achieves this (I believe) by returning an `std::vector<int> &&` instead of an `std::vector<int>`. Option 3 achieves this (I believe) by adding a new parameter with a default option. All three options require changes in the client code to take advantage of the optimization, which is acceptable.

Comment: `clear()` followed by `push_back()` might actually deallocate and then allocate vector storage on some implementations, even if none of the major ones do. I would prefer `ret.assign(1, 20+i);`

Comment: @ComeRaczy But option 1 does the same thing as your original code. Just with an extra function call. Unless the client code starts using the new function. But your constraint rules that out (it assumes client code does not change). Option 2 changes `foo`'s semantics, perhaps destructively. Option 3 has the same problem as option 1. That's what I'm saying. Either the client code can change, or it can't. Which is it!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry for not being clear enough. I am not sure if I can formulate it more successfully in yet another way but let me try again: there are two different use cases. There is the case where performance does not matter and where the client code should still compile and work without any change. Then there is another different and non overlapping case where performance is important and where it is acceptable to change the client code to speed things up.

Comment: So what you're really saying is that adding functionality and options is permitted, as long as API (_not_ binary) backward compatibility is maintained.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes with the caveat that it is a very loose and somewhat flexible interpretation of API backward compatibility. It is acceptable to change the signature of the function and to even replace the function with something else (macro, lambda, operator(), etc.) as long as the existing code still compiles and still produces the expected result in reasonable and common use cases.

Comment: Hmm that sounds kind of dangerous. I'd _want_ the build to break in cases like that, forcing the client programmer to make sure the function is still what they want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cache of vectors,

```
#include"my_global_cache.h";
std::vector<int> & foo(int i,int id=0) {
  auto ret  = myCache<int>(i,id); // uses a map and some thread-safetiness
                                  // or an extra thread id instead
                                  // static thread_local int thread_id = myGlobalAtomicCtr++;
  return ret;
}
```

and a macro (I'm sorry for this)

```
#define foo(i) foo(i,__LINE__)
```

so that you can decorate client codes automatically with cached id values

```
auto clientVect  = foo(i); // returns cached 232th vector
auto clientVect2 = foo(i); // returns cached 233th vector
```

Then, to fix(I'm sorry) duplicate calls from different compilation units, you may also use `__FILE__` from the macros as a third parameter to cache function.

This way they should return same vector per unique id,pageId value while allocating it internally only when id doesn't exist,lazily.

Or even this:

```
#define foo(i) myCache(i,__LINE__,__FILE__)
```

so it directly comes from cache, without being forced to swap/move explicitly.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
   auto v1 = foo(1); // allocates when i=0, reuses when i=1
   auto v2 = foo(1); // allocates when i=0, reuses when i=1
   compute(v1,v2);
}
```

Note: myCache should return by reference so that client can choose to re-use it or have a copy.

Comment: This looks like an interesting direction and it might be an appropriate answer if  several important details were addressed. Particularly, unless I missed some important aspects of your suggestion, the actual implementation of the cache might present some challenges in terms of size management, thread safety and performance. For instance, as your solution now returns a reference to a specific cache id, this would need to be either unique to a thread (requiring additional thread management) or locked (leading to several issues with multi-threaded applications).

Comment: Unless a new vector is needed in cache, reusing one would not need lock. Only adding into cache and requesting a new one would need a lock. If you have a loop, first iteration would lock unlock for allocation but all other iterations wouldnt need because they already have their data which allocated by themselves on something like a std::map. Does Reading map element need lock even if element is not deleted by other thread? Maybe atomic counter is enough to separate elements of vector of vector? Atomics simpler and faster than lock.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something because your answer doesn't provide the implementation, but the way I understand it, if two threads concurrently execute `foo(int)` from he same line of code, they will concurrently use the same cached vector. If that's the case then there will be a need to control concurrent access to that cached vector. If that's not the case then I probably failed to understand your suggestion.

Comment: If you are spawning threads yourself, maybe you know their index? Then you could add it to line number? Or multiply them?

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

If people are already using this function, then they wrote their code knowing that it would return a vector by value, a vector with which they could do whatever they please.

If you now change it to return a reference to some shared/re-used vector instead, *that is breaking the semantics of the function* and unless you are very careful can cause a lot of pain.

Instead, provide a new function that takes in a vector and populates it, rather than creating a new one. Have the clients use the new function when appropriate. Can't change the code? Sure you can. There's always a way.

Comment: Should I delete my answer? Or add "use at your own risk" like warning?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Nothing wrong with having different answers